# How to filter post based on post type

Tags: laravel

```
$project = Categorie::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('projects')->get();
```

I want to show project which status is Public
I can use status in project like this but i can not able to use this in above query.

```
 $project = Project::orderBy('created_at,'DESC')->where('status','=','Public')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereHas()` method

```
$categories = Categorie::with("projects")->whereHas('projects', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'Public');
})->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
  ->get();
```